# Joomla CiviCRM 4.7.6 : Error Messages html displayed as text

Tags: joomla, error, error-page

Why do all error messages display as text? For example, even the demo at http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/index.php?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/petition/sign&sid=1&reset=1 displays the error in plain text. What can be done to fix this?

> #0 <div id="crm-container" class="crm-container" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
>     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
>       @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css);
>       @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css);
>     </style>
>   <div class="messages status no-popup">  <div class="icon red-icon ui-icon-alert"></div>
>    <span class="status-fatal">Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.</span>
>       <div class="crm-section crm-error-message">You do not have permission to access this page.</div>
>               <p><a href="http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/" title="Main Menu">Return to home page.</a></p>
>   </div>
>   </div> 
>   <script language="JavaScript">
>   function toggle( element ) {
>       var className = element.className;
>       if ( className  == 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block') {
>           element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper  crm-fatal-error-details-block';
>       } else {
>           element.className = 'crm-accordion-wrapper collapsed crm-fatal-error-details-block';
>       }
>   }
>   </script>

Comment: It also happen to me, I've never gone to see why, but I'm with you on that.

Comment: This is a nuisance... And it has been asked once in a while without any answers that I have found, e.g. https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32267.msg138007#msg138007

Comment: And here's actually a CiviCRM-exchange question with some limited info: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2340/how-can-i-set-up-the-default-civicrm-error-page-message-inside-the-site-template